# Sendgrid how get click tracking link

Tags: sendgrid, amp-email

When I made `clickTracking: true` option in @sendgrid/mail API v3, this is work fine and my links modified, but when I use AMP-emails I have dynamic custom links and I can't trigger click event. I need a way, how get this modified link which triggers the click event, or I need a option how send click event data to API sendgrid. I need to manually trigger a click event.

Example of a modified link:

```
http://ur123456.website.com/ls/click?upn=GNQ0Y-2FRud123pJSNJOPFTPfjwJ-2F9X71r7qLU3SBdb4745wVI-3DEtcA_nx1QKxP5K9TFoBZ-2Fz3K-2FiEAlKmIrVx72dFsYBr12fl-2Br8WvWtRge-2B9lHeVXh0HaMja395gHzISC7UDCV1231dOTaWPhiq-2FAFaKGi2qym7shXhIH0Su5b4w4-2FfERisM06r5GHpIuvzvJLmai9qztFocXEBsHeqF-2Fjp-2FeilXXlqngdgvkDDttn9-2FxmOn8zQomq5xL63f8xfuF7ikp123W3PXyGTH2-2BzyQNgEm6Nsxv123MzdkpBfFOpg-3D
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

I don't know of a way to manually trigger a click event, but there are some workarounds to have dynamic custom links. According to this page in the docs on [click tracking best practices](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/analytics-and-reporting/click-tracking-html-best-practices) if you can still include the domain, it will still work:

> `<a href="{{ birthday_url }}"></a>` will not work. Instead you should format your link like this: `<a href="http://yoursite.com/{{ birthday_url }}"></a>`

Comment: In AMP-email, the `href` attribute can change, be dynamic. I'll prepare a demo and show it to you.

Comment: Here demo: https://alexkazakov.info/layout/amp-email-sendgrid-support-demo/ As you can see, the link is dynamic, and yes this it work fine in gmail.  Я отправил эту демонстрацию на адрес электронной почты службы поддержки sendgrid.

Comment: Rather than making the `href` of the link dynamic, could you use AMP to render all the links and only show one at a time? That way the tracking could be set up on each link.